# how to convert a date time string unto a specified date time format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs

Anyone knows how to convert this

```
Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)
```

to

```
2015-12-02 00:00:00
```

any ideas, help, clues, suggestions, recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is "Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)" derived ?

Comment: I'm using some sort of a plugin that gives me a creation date of the created event and the date format is like that which outfitted on my requirements that's why I want to format the time from the given format above.

Comment: You can parse it with a regular expression and return on the digits to an array that you can then manipulate to provide a rearranged value in line with your expectations.

Comment: any demo or sample from your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

```
var time = 'Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)';
var format = moment(time).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iplus26/cfgbL2ng/).

Comment: short and accurate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var temp = new Date("Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)");
console.log(temp.getFullYear() + "-"  +(temp.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + temp.getDate());
console.log(temp.getHours() + ":" + temp.getMinutes() + ":" + temp.getSeconds());
```

Comment: cool. but the time returns "0:0:0" which it should be "00:00:00".

Comment: You can put a ternary to check if < 10 and the extra 0 or just go with momentjs.

Comment: write padLeft function like here : ` function(value, padding) {
            var zeroes = "0";
            for (var i = 0; i < padding; i++) {
                zeroes += "0";
            }
            return (zeroes + value).slice(padding * -1);
        } `

Comment: call it like: padLeft(temp.getFullYear(),2)

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = Date.parse("Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800");
d = new Date(d).toLocaleString();
```

use this then:

```
var d = Date.parse("Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800");
d = new Date(d).toLocaleString();
d.replace(/\d+\/\d+\/\d{4},/, function (x){
   x = x.replace(/,/, "");
   x = x.split("/");
   return x[2] + "-" + x[1] + "-" + x[0]; 
});
```

Comment: cool but, it returns "02/12/2015, 00:00:00" , I need "2015-12-02 00:00:00" base from the above given format. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, had to run downstairs. Forget the regex, just slice it up and use it together like this. (http://jsfiddle.net/u2xn2Lv5/1/)

JS:

```
var origTime = "Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)";
//or function you call to derive this data stringified

var dayVal = origTime.slice(8,10);
var yearVal = origTime.slice(11,15);
var monthVal = origTime.slice(4,7);
var timeVal = origTime.slice(16,23);
var newDate = ""; // Hasn't been set yet
//alert(monthVal);
switch(monthVal) {
    case "Dec":
        newDate = "12";
        break;
    case "Jan":
        newDate = "1";
        break;
    case "Jun":
        newDate = "6";
        break;
    default:
        "unknown month!"
};

var newTime =  newDate + "-" + dayVal + "-" + yearVal + "-" + timeVal;
document.getElementById("spanthing").innerHTML = newTime;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="spanthing"></div>
```

To be rearranged as needed! Cheers!

Comment: Wait, if you return "Thursday" and "Wednesday" and "Tuesday" do you get "Thu", "Wed", and "Tue" ?  Because if you get "Weds" "Thurs" and "Tues" I have to give you an update for the altered array positions?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
moment(yourDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```